# Writing to two output streams using template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, static-cast, nullptr

I'm trying to make a logging library where the user would be able to choose to write to the output or a file or both. I want to make a single class that handles the writing (and later on other stream related stuff).

The obvious implementation would be to use an if statement for all functionalities but I wanted to optimize that out using template specialization. I created a class called `DoubleStreamWriter`:

```cpp
template <typename _FST, typename _OST>
class DoubleStreamWriter {
public:
    DoubleStreamWriter(_FST fst, _OST ost) {
        fst_ = fst;
        ost_ = ost;
    }
    template <typename WT>
    void Write(WT obj) {
        (*fst_) << obj;
        (*ost_) << obj;
    }
    void Flush() {
        fst_->flush();
        ost_->flush();
    }

private:
    _FST fst_;
    _OST ost_;
};

template <>
class DoubleStreamWriter <std::nullptr_t, std::ostream*> {
public:
    DoubleStreamWriter(std::nullptr_t fst, std::ostream* ost) {
        (void)fst;
        ost_ = ost;
    }
    template <typename WT>
    void Write(WT obj) {
        (*ost_) << obj;
    }
    void Flush() {
        ost_->flush();
    }

private:
    std::ostream* ost_;
};

template <>
class DoubleStreamWriter <std::ofstream*, std::nullptr_t> {
public:
    DoubleStreamWriter(std::ofstream* fst, std::nullptr_t ost) {
        (void)ost;
        fst_ = fst;
    }
    template <typename WT>
    void Write(WT obj) {
        (*fst_) << obj;
    }
    void Flush() {
        fst_->flush();  
    }

private:
    static std::ofstream* fst_;
};

template <>
class DoubleStreamWriter <std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t> {
public:
    DoubleStreamWriter(std::nullptr_t fst, std::nullptr_t ost) {
        (void)fst;
        (void)ost;
        std::cout << ">>> cannot log anything with those settings" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename WT>
    void Write(WT obj) {
        (void)obj;
    }
    void Flush() {

    }
};
```

The logger class is a singleton that has a private pointer (`dwriter_`) of this type. However, I obviously cannot change the type of the templates during initialization, e.g. cannot convert `DoubleStreamWriter<ofstream*, ostream*>` to `DoubleStreamWriter <std::nullptr_t, ostream*>`. I tried to "fix" it by using a `void*` instead but that just postponed the issue to runtime and is very ugly.

My mistake was that I thought `decltype(stream_ptr)` returns `std::nullptr_t` if `stream_ptr` is set to `nullptr`.

What would be the best way of doing this? alternatively, is there a way of getting the same type as `decltype(nullptr)` when calling `decltype` on a pointer set to `nullptr`?

Comment: Are you over-complicating things? Couldn't you just use an untemplated `MultistreamWriter` that stores a vector of ostream pointers? If you go with a templated approach, what will be the type stored in the logger?

Comment: @HKrishnan I had the doubt that I am. For the actual logging I've been using so many templated types, it wasn't really thinking of anything else. The end goal was to not have any overhead but my approach is simply wrong and won't work. As you pointed out, the type is pre-set if I use templates and using a void* will cause a segfault because the wrong Write() gets called during runtime. Thanks